# Hide MATLAB legend entries for some graphical objects in plots

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

MATLAB legends list everything in a plot, including guidelines that you have put on a plot.

A fudge to get around that is to do

```
*Plot
*Add legend
*Add guidelines
```

However, MATLAB puts the most recent lines in the front, meaning the guidelines then sit over the displayed data; ugly and distracting.

Similar problems occur any time you build up a complicated plot, `legend` freaks out and grabs everything, and workarounds with plotting order can be ugly

Example code:

```
%**** Optional guidelines
figure(1)
plot([2 2],[0,1],'k--'); hold on

%**** DATA
N = 4;
y=rand(5,N);
x=1:1:5;
for plotLoop=1:N;
  %* Plot
  figure(1)
  plot(x,y(plotLoop,:));
  hold on
end

%*****LEGEND
hLegend = legend(LegTxt,...
                'interpreter','latex',...
                'location','eastoutside')
```

(move the code block order to replicate the situations mentioned above)

How to reasonably fix this?

Comment: I have updated the title to make it a bit more general - it may not only be guidelines, but e.g. errobars or similar that you don't want to show up as legend entry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a certain graphics object to not produce a legend (and that will work even if you toggle the legend off and on again), you can modify the `LegendInformation`:

```
%# plot something that shouldn't show up as legend
handleWithoutLegend = plot(something);

%# modify the LegendInformation of the Annotation-Property of the graphical object
set(get(get(handleWithoutLegend,'Annotation'),'LegendInformation'),...
    'IconDisplayStyle','off');

%# toggle legend on and off at will, and never see the something-object appear
```

If you try to turn off the legend on an array of handles, the best way is just to loop over them, with a try-wrapper for graphical objects that cannot produce a legend:

```
for h = listOfHandles(:)'
   try
      set(get(get(h,'Annotation'),'LegendInformation'),...
        'IconDisplayStyle','off');
   end
end
```

Comment: I recommend packing this command into a function "noLegend" or something, because I honestly cannot remember it otherwise.

Comment: I tried using the code and get the error `Conversion to double from cell is not possible.` for `get(bla, 'LegendInformation')`.   Do you know why?  I assume the code only works for some graphics objects, and not all?

Comment: @Mark_Anderson: I've now added a loop solution that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Craft a custom handle that you feed into the `legend`.  Plot handles can be concatenated to form an object that legend is happy to accept as input.

The required code isn't pretty, but it does work.

```
%**** Optional guidelines for periodicity
figure(1)
plot([2 2],[0,1],'k--'); hold on

%**** DATA
N = 4;
y=rand(5,N);
x=1:1:5;

for plotLoop=1:N;
  LegTxt{plotLoop} = num2str(plotLoop);
  %* Plot
  figure(1)

  % if statement to construct a handle for the legend later
  if plotLoop==1 
      htot=plot(x,y(plotLoop,:));
  else
      h=plot(x,y(plotLoop,:));
      % Append this info to the figure handle
      htot= [htot, h];
  end
  hold on

end

%*****LEGEND
hLegend = legend(htot,LegTxt,...
                'interpreter','latex','FontSize',16,...
                'location','eastoutside')
```

For the pedantic or curious, the loop `for plotLoop=1:N;` is here because I extracted the example from some rather complex code where the data is extracted from cell arrays.  Obviously you could eliminate that loop for a lot of usage scenarios, I just decided to keep the code in its most flexible format!

Comment: This works, but if you manually toggle the legend off and then back on again, the unwanted items still appear. Fortunately, there is another solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42471561/232610

Comment: Fair enough, I never use the manual plot interaction tools in MATLAB so I hadn't come across the problem!

Comment: You can [preallocate an array for graphics handles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gobjects.html): `htot=gobjects(1,N)`. Then you can do `htot(plotLoop) = plot(...)`. Also, you can add the legend text to the plot command itself, which would further simplify this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also hide plot from legend in another way. Here's the sample:

```
figure(1)
hold on

x=1:10;
y1=x;
y2=x.^2/10;
y3=x.^3/100;

plot(x,y1);
plot(x,y2,'HandleVisibility','off');
plot(x,y3);

legend('x','x^3')
```

You just need to put `'HandleVisibility', 'off'` to your plot that you don't want to show up in legend. That's how result looks like:

[image: sample result]

`HandleVisibility` is a line property so it might now work if you create plot in some other way. But for most use cases its enough and it is much simpler.