# How to prevent the legend from updating in R2017a and newer?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, legend

Since MATLAB R2017a, figure legends update automatically when adding a plot to axes. Previously, one could do this:

```matlab
data = randn(100,4);
plot(data)
legend('line1','line2','line3','line4')
hold on
plot([1,100],[0,0],'k-')
```

to plot four data lines with a legend, and then add a black line for y=0. However, since R2017a, this leads to the black line being added to the legend, with the name "data1".

How do I prevent this line from being added to the legend, so that the code behaves like it did in older versions of MATLAB?

The only solution I have found so far on Stack Overflow is to [remove the legend item after it has been added](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42471440/7328782). The syntax is not pretty:

```matlab
h = plot([1,100],[0,0],'k-'); % keep a handle to the added line
set(get(get(h,'Annotation'),'LegendInformation'),'IconDisplayStyle','off');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The release notes for MATLAB R2017a [mention this change](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=legend&startrelease=R2017a&endrelease=R2017a&category=Graphics&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=legend), and provide 4 different ways of handling the situation. These two methods are easiest to put into existing code:

---

**1:** Turn off auto updating for the legend before adding the black line. This can be done at creation time:

```matlab
legend({'line1','line2','line3','line4'}, 'AutoUpdate','off')
```

or after:

```matlab
h = findobj(gcf,'type','legend');
set(h, 'AutoUpdate','off')
```

You can also change the default for all future legends:

```matlab
set(groot,'defaultLegendAutoUpdate','off')
```

---

**2:** Turn off handle visibility for the black line that you don't want added to the legend:

```matlab
plot([1,100],[0,0],'k-', 'HandleVisibility','off')
```

---

The `IconDisplayStyle` method is also shown here. However, they use the dot notation, which makes the syntax is a bit prettier:

```matlab
h = plot([1,100],[0,0],'k-'); % keep a handle to the added line
h.Annotation.LegendInformation.IconDisplayStyle = 'off';
```